# Доступ к объектам в массиве указателей

Tags: c++

К примеру у меня есть 2 массива указателей:

```
Vidannya* arr[3];
arr[0]=new Knygy[n];
arr[1]=new Gasety[p];
```

n, p - количество обьектов данного производного класса.

---

Как при n,p >1 получить доступ к остальным объектам, а не только к одному?

Comment: Примерно так: `arr[i][j]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как каждый элемент массива arr - это массив, то в

```
arr[i][j]
```

i - это индекс массива в котором храняться указатели на однотипные объекты (Knygy или Gasety), а j - это индекс непосредственно указателя на конкретный объект

вот так например

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Vidannya{
public:
 virtual void printName() = 0;
};
class Knygy : public Vidannya{
public:
 virtual void printName(){
  cout << "Knygy" << endl;
 }
};
class Gasety : public Vidannya{
public:
 virtual void printName(){
  cout << "Gasety" << endl;
 }
};

int main() {
    int n = 3, p = 3;
    Vidannya*arr[2];
    arr[0]=new Knygy[n];
    arr[1]=new Gasety[p];

    arr[0][0].printName();
    arr[0][1].printName();
    arr[1][0].printName();
    arr[1][0].printName();

    return 0;
}
```